# Subtracting many columns in a df by one column in another df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to substract a df "stock_returns" (144 rows x 517 col) by a df "p_df" (144 rows x 1 col).

I have tried;

```
stock_returns - p_df

stock_returns.rsub(p_df,axis=1)
stock_returns.substract(p_df)
```

But none of them work and all return Nan values.

I'm passing it through this fnc, and using the for loop to get args:

```
def disp_calc(returns, p, wi):    #apply(disp_calc, rows = ...)
    wi = wi/np.sum(wi)
    rp = (col_len(returns)*(returns-p)**2).sum()      #returns - p causing problems    
    return np.sqrt(rp)

for i in sectors:
    stock_returns = returns_rolling[sectordict[i]]#.apply(np.mean,axis=1)          
    portfolio_return = returns_rolling[i]; p_df = portfolio_return.to_frame()
    disp_df[i] = stock_returns.apply(disp_calc,args=(portfolio_return,wi))
```

My expected output is to subtract all 517 cols in the first df  by the 1 col in p_df. so final results would still have 517 cols. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

You're almost there, just need to set `axis=0` to subtract along the indexes:

```
>>> stock_returns = pd.DataFrame([[10,100,200], 
                             [15, 115, 215], 
                             [20,120, 220], 
                             [25,125,225], 
                             [30,130,230]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']) 
>>> stock_returns

   A    B    C
0  10  100  200
1  15  115  215
2  20  120  220
3  25  125  225
4  30  130  230

>>> p_df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=['P'])
>>> p_df

   P
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

>>> stock_returns.sub(p_df['P'], axis=0)

    A    B    C
0   9   99  199
1  13  113  213
2  17  117  217
3  21  121  221
4  25  125  225
```

Comment: awesome that works outside the fnc, but it doesnt work when I write in the function,     rp = (col_len(returns)*(returns.sub(p,axis=0)**2)).sum()

Comment: Ah, I didn't read that part of the question carefully enough.  Let me take a closer look

Comment: The code, as presented, is a little difficult to sort through out of context.  What is `col_len(returns)` ?  Is that a numpy array? A single number?

Comment: actually you can ignore that , thats for the weights of the stocks but Im just going to make it equal weighted

Answer (score 0):

```
data['new_col3'] = data['col1'] - data['col2']
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See this [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to properly format code. Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: I like your script. But please remember that code-only answers should not be deleted. Instead, if you feel strongly, downvote them.

Comment: @JeremyCaney "code only answers" is not a valid reason by SO to delete an answer, since I've received flack before for wanting to delete answers like this (and downvoting 20 answers every time I review would plamit my reputation) I chose to comment to improve the answer

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: That’s correct. But you voted to delete it, which is why I left the comment. I’ll assume it was an accidental click? Good feedback regardless.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks, though I voted to delete cause there's already a highvoted answer and it didn't seem to add anything new